# control vertical space before and after verbatim environment?

Tags: spacing, verbatim

How do I control how much vertical space appears before and after a `verbatim` environment?

With the following source (run through `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
text before verbatim
\begin{verbatim}
some verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
text after verbatim
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image: bad behavior]

I would like to be able to tweak things to get the following behavior:

[image: good behavior]

**Edit:**

I would also like the solution to work for `verbatim` environments in a list item:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item text before verbatim
\begin{verbatim}
some verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
text after verbatim
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad behavior in a list]

Comment: If you don't need `verbatim` text, you can always use `\ttfamily` or `\texttt{...}` and then have the regular paragraph skip between the lines.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`verbatim` uses `trivlist` which adds above and below it the current values of `\topsep` and `\partopsep` (the latter if at the beginning of a paragraph); since the `trivlist` is started when a group has already been opened by `verbatim`, it's safe to set locally the values: the command to patch is `\@verbatim`, that starts with `\trivlist`, so we can set the parameters just before this command:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt }
\makeatother
```

Here's an example, where I put two `minipage` environments next to each other just to show the line spacing:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
text before verbatim
\begin{verbatim}
some verbatim text
\end{verbatim}
text after verbatim
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
abc\\
def\\
ghi
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic!  thank you!  do you happen to have a version that works with `enumitem` up your sleeve?  :)

Comment: @RichardHansen It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The `enumitem` package apparently modifies `\trivlist` to restore spacing to defaults.  This allows it to modify the spacing for normal lists without affecting spacing for `verbatim` and others.  Unfortunately, it means that your solution won't work if `enumitem` is in use.

Comment: @RichardHansen I get identical results with `enumitem`; can you add an example to your question?

Comment: I was wrong---it's not `enumitem`'s fault.  The `verbatim` still has space above and below when in a list environment (see edited question).  Your solution reduces that space, but there's still some there.  I'm guessing something else is responsible for that space...

Comment: It seems that `\AtBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\setlist[trivlist]{nolistsep}}` works. `\setlist[trivlist]{nolistsep}` can be found in the document of `enumitem` (Section 12).