# How can I fix verbatim causing an extra newline inside a description list environment?

Tags: lists, line-breaking, verbatim, description

I'm trying to create a documentation listing similar to that used by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915.aspx). Here was my first attempt at that:

```
\subsubsection{User Default Page URL}
\begin{description}
\item[Rationale] This is the default page displayed to a user when
(s)he opens a new window or tab in Microsoft's Internet Explorer browser.
\item[Data Sources] \begin{verbatim}
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer]
"Default_Page_URL"="${url}"
\end{verbatim}
\item[Log Format] \begin{verbatim} 
uDefaultPageUrl=${url}
\end{verbatim}
\item[Description] The variable \var{url} is escaped using the URL
escaping scheme defined in \ref{urlescape}.
\end{description}
```

Which produces:

[image: example output]

Of course, this is wrong behavior -- the registry key bit needs to go on it's own, not pushed over to the right on the first line. I tried following the instructions on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35481/description-list-how-to-put-the-definition-on-a-new-line), which left this:

```
\subsubsection{User Default Page URL}
\begin{description}
\item[Rationale] \hfill \\ This is the default page displayed to a user when
(s)he opens a new window or tab in Microsoft's Internet Explorer browser.
\item[Data Sources] \hfill \\ \begin{verbatim}
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer]
"Default_Page_URL"="${url}"
\end{verbatim}
\item[Log Format] \hfill \\ \begin{verbatim} 
uDefaultPageUrl=${url}
\end{verbatim}
\item[Description] \hfill \\ The variable \var{url} is escaped using the URL
escaping scheme defined in \ref{urlescape}.
\end{description}
```

producing:

[image: example longer output]

This is bad because now there's a huge space before the verbatim text. Also, XeTeX decided to complain quite a bit about bad boxes on this one.

I've tried several "massagings" of this -- such as removing the explicit newline after the `\hline` on Verbatim environments only. That shrinks the space, but not enough -- it still looks like a huge gaping hole.

How would one fix this?

**EDIT**: In response to the comment:

```
\subsubsection{User Default Page URL}

\begin{description}
\item[Rationale] This is the default page displayed to a user when
(s)he opens a new window or tab in Microsoft's Internet Explorer browser.
\item[Data Sources] \hfill

\begin{verbatim}
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer]
"Default_Page_URL"="${url}"
\end{verbatim}
\item[Log Format]
\begin{verbatim} 
uDefaultPageUrl=${url}
\end{verbatim}
\item[Description] The variable \var{url} is escaped using the URL
escaping scheme defined in \ref{urlescape}.

\end{description}
```

produces:

[image: Still spaced]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is  better method, but it seems that if you eliminate the `\\` and include a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` before the `verbatim` environment you get reasonable looking results:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\var}[1]{\texttt{#1}}%  Macro definition not provided in MWE

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{User Default Page URL}

\begin{description}
\item[Rationale] \hfill 

This is the default page displayed to a user when
(s)he opens a new window or tab in Microsoft's Internet Explorer browser.
\item[Data Sources] \hfill\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{verbatim}
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer]
"Default_Page_URL"="${url}"
\end{verbatim}
\item[Log Format] \hfill \vspace{-\baselineskip}
%
\begin{verbatim} 
uDefaultPageUrl=${url}
\end{verbatim}
\item[Description] \hfill 

The variable \var{url} is escaped using the URL
escaping scheme defined in \ref{urlescape}.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include var :) That looks awesome.. thank you. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the solution provided in [Control vertical space before and after verbatim environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43331/5764), here is a version of your MWE that is properly aligned:

[image]

```
% Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43638/
% Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43331/
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily\string$\string{#1\string}\egroup}%$
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}\setcounter{subsection}{2}% Just for this example
\subsubsection{User Default Page URL}

\begin{description}
\item[Rationale] This is the default page displayed to a user when
(s)he opens a new window or tab in Microsoft's Internet Explorer browser.
\item[Data Sources] \hspace*{\fill} \\[-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\parskip\relax]
\begin{verbatim}
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer]
"Default_Page_URL"="${url}"
\end{verbatim}
\item[Log Format] \hspace*{\fill} \\[-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\parskip\relax]
\begin{verbatim} 
uDefaultPageUrl=${url}
\end{verbatim}
\item[Description] The variable \var{url} is escaped using the URL
escaping scheme defined in~3.2.1.

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Here is a comparable view using inline verbatim (via `\verb`) to show the corresponding vertical alignment. On the left is a section of the above output, while the code below is added to the right:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily\string$\string{#1\string}\egroup}%$
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}\setcounter{subsection}{2}% Just for this example
\subsubsection{User Default Page URL}

\begin{description}
\item[Rationale] This is the default page displayed to a user when
(s)he opens a new window or tab in Microsoft's Internet Explorer browser.
\item[Data Sources] \hspace*{\fill} \\
\verb|[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer]| \\
\verb|"Default_Page_URL"="${url}"|
\item[Log Format] \hspace*{\fill} \\
\verb|uDefaultPageUrl=${url}|
\item[Description] The variable \var{url} is escaped using the URL
escaping scheme defined in~3.2.1.

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused.. what's the difference in the output?

Comment: @BillyONeal: The difference between my output in the first example and that of @ PeterGrill's answer is minimal. However, when you put his and mine next to one another, you'll notice the difference. The reason being that the `verbatim` environment is set as a list (`trivlist`), which adds a little space above/at the beginning (see the linked post). There's no difference in the output of the last example even though the left image is created using the `verbatim` environment, compared to the inline `\verb` for the right image.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. (Sorry for being a dullard at such things)

Comment: @BillyONeal: More specific to @ PeterGrill's answer: You'll notice that the height from the item label to the first line is smaller in the `verbatim` items than in the regular items. As I mentioned this may be negligible to most people.

Comment: Yeah; if I was publishing a book or something then this does look more consistent. Unfortunately it's a lot more code to do per-entry :(