# How to suppress extra vertical space before/after fancy Verbatim environments?

Tags: spacing, fancyvrb

I am using fancyvrb's `DefineVerbatimEnvironment` to create differently-styled verbatim environments for user input and output. When two or more of these follow each other, there is extra vertical space between them.  According to [control vertical space before and after verbatim environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43331/control-vertical-space-before-and-after-verbatim-environment), that extra space can be suppressed by re-setting `\topsep` or `\partopsetp` for a regular `verbatim`. How can/should I suppress it for an environment defined using `DefineVerbatimEnvironment`?

Example showing the extra inter-block spacing I want to suppress:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbIn}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\relsize{-1}}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOut}{Verbatim}{fontshape=it,fontsize=\relsize{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{VerbIn}
This is user input.
\end{VerbIn}
\begin{VerbOut}
This is user output.
\end{VerbOut}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot showing extra inter-block spacing]

*Later: egreg's solution sometimes works:*

[image: VerbInX solution working]

*but sometimes doesn't:*

[image: VerbInX solution not working]

*Steven's `verbatimbox` solution works, but will be clunky in practice: there are often sequences of immediately consecutive in-out-in-out-in-out, all of which should have spaces suppressed, and having to give each one a unique token for later recall will be error-prone to edit.*

*Later: if you are comfortable using Git, I have committed egreg's solution in a branch:*

```
$ git clone git@github.com:gvwilson/bc.git
$ cd bc
$ git checkout book
$ cd book
$ make # or 'pdflatex book' a couple of times
$ open book.pdf # and go to the bottom of pg 8 or the top of pg 10
```

*Packages are loaded in `packages.tex`, and commands are defined in `commands.tex`*.

Comment: I imagine you want to suppress the spacing only when `VerbOut` immediately follows `VerbIn`. Does a `VerbOut` always follow a `VerbIn`?

Comment: No: sometimes there's plain text between the input and output. And sometimes there's a sequence of in-out-in-out, all of which should have the spaces suppressed.

Comment: Can you add the code for the non working case and clearly specify the use cases?

Comment: Instructions added to main body (I can't seem to put <pre> blocks in comments).

Comment: For consecutive in-out constructions, one may use the `verbbox` environment, rather than `myverbbox`.  In the former case, no unique token name is specified.  Rather, the "generic" verbbox is recalled with `\theverbbox`.  I have  updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is an undocumented `fancyvrb` option, called `listparameters`. You can pass list dimension changing codes to this option. [Here](https://latexref.xyz/list.html#list) is a full list of list dimensions and their roles. To suppress the above and below vertical spaces, you can use

```
listparameters=\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}

\fvset{listparameters=\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbIn}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\relsize{-1}}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOut}{Verbatim}{fontshape=it,fontsize=\relsize{-1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent normal text
\begin{VerbIn}
This is user input.
\end{VerbIn}
normal text
\begin{VerbOut}
This is user output.
\end{VerbOut}
normal text

\end{document}
```

[image: use option "listparameters" to remove vertical skips]

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! It works for the space on top but it doesn't for the space below. Could you have a look at [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/687779/33287), its reply, and the comments?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to suppress the vertical space when a `VerbOut` environment immediately follows a `VerbIn`, this should work:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbInX}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\relsize{-1}}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbOutX}{Verbatim}{fontshape=it,fontsize=\relsize{-1}}
\newenvironment{VerbIn}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
   \par\VerbInX}
  {\endVerbInX\vskip1sp }
\newenvironment{VerbOut}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
   \par\ifdim\lastskip=1sp\vspace{\dimexpr-2\topsep-2\partopsep\relax}\fi
   \VerbOutX}
  {\endVerbOutX}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{VerbIn}
This is user input.
\end{VerbIn}
\begin{VerbOut}
This is user output.
\end{VerbOut}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{VerbIn}
This is user input.
\end{VerbIn}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

At the end of `VerbIn` I add a special invisible vertical skip of just 1sp (the least positive length in TeX). At the beginning of `VerbOut` I check if such vertical skip is present, which should only be the case when `VerbIn` has just ended.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `verbatimbox` package as an alternative.  By placing the verbatim content in boxes, and then outputting the boxes, the extra line can be avoided.

I have EDITED my answer to show two ways to achieve the result with the package.  In the first case the `myverbbox` environment requires a token name to be associated with the created box.  In this way, the verbatim material can be created well in advance of its actual use (unless the token is reutilized).

In the second case, the `verbbox` environment does not use a unique token name in which to store the verbatim box; rather, the content is stored in the generic box that is recalled with `\theverbbox`.  This technique is more efficient if the box can be used as soon as it is created.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}[\relsize{-1}]{\VerbIn}
This is user input.
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[\itshape\relsize{-1}]{\VerbOut}
This is user output.
\end{myverbbox}
\noindent\VerbIn\\\VerbOut

\begin{verbbox}[\relsize{-1}]
This is user input.
\end{verbbox}
\noindent\theverbbox\\
\begin{verbbox}[\itshape\relsize{-1}]
This is user output.
\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox
\end{document}
```

[image]