# minitoc suppress before/after space

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, minitoc

Is there any way to easily customize `\minitoc` to avoid the big before/after space?

Without using `\vspace{-5mm}` everywhere I use them (which is in a lot of chapters), and, only as a last case recourse, without resorting to hacks such as this: [How to suppress extra vertical space before/after fancy Verbatim environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184019/how-to-suppress-extra-vertical-space-before-after-fancy-verbatim-environments).

The minitoc manual is too huge for me to parse it, and my latex skills are still in their infancy. :)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\dominitoc

\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}

\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}

The following topics will be explojlkmemdl.dm,dl d,wd,dw dwwfeefr ffwfewefef feef feeffe red:
\minitoc

\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One Two}


\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minitoc}
% this
\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{before}{\vspace{-.5cm}}
\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{after}{\vspace{-.5cm}}
% or this
%\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{open}{\vspace{-.5cm}}
%\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{close}{\vspace{-.5cm}}

\dominitoc

\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}

\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}

The following topics will be explojlkmemdl.dm,dl d,wd,dw dwwfeefr ffwfewefef feef feeffe red:
\minitoc

\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One One}
\subsection{Subsection One One Two}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{before}{\vspace{-...}}` didn't work for me. After a lot of frustration I realised that I needed the starred version of `\vspace`, i.e.: `\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{before}{\vspace*{-...}}`