# Control vertical space after Verbatim environment

Tags: environments, verbatim, fancyvrb

I want to control the vertical space after a `Verbatim` environment from `fancyvrb`. Even setting `\topsep` and `\partopsep` to `0pt`, as suggested in [**muzimuzhi**'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534447/33287), gives me some extra spacing after the boxed code.

```
\documentclass{article}\setlength{\textwidth}{200pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{listparameters=\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1]

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
  Some content
  here, with its
  own box
\end{Verbatim}

\lipsum[2][1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the worse case, I can simply add a negative space in my custom environment definition. But I'd rather understand what's going on here and avoid creating patches due to my ignorance of the current spacing situation.

P.S. It would be nice asking `pdftex` to print out the boxes and glue used here to figure out what's going on.

### Debugging

- Using `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` globally does nothing.
- Adding `\nointerlineskip` right after the `Verbatim` environment fixes the issue, although I'm not sure why (see comments to the accepted answer for an explanation).

[image]

Comment: Well the sep below is actually caused by the frame setting. With `frame=lines` (`frame=topline`) you can even see extra separation at top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `\prevdepth\dp\strutbox` after the environment

```
\documentclass{article}\setlength{\textwidth}{200pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{listparameters=\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1]

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
  Some content
  here, with its
  own box
\end{Verbatim}
\prevdepth\dp\strutbox

\indent\smash{\rule{1pt}{\ht\strutbox}}\lipsum[2][1]
\end{document}
```

(the `\rule` for demo only; `\indent` tacitly implied by `\smash` in recent LaTeX at least)

[image: output]

Or with modern LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}\setlength{\textwidth}{200pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{listparameters=\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}}

\AddToHook{env/Verbatim/after}{\prevdepth\dp\strutbox}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1]

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
  Some content
  here, with its
  own box
\end{Verbatim}

\lipsum[2][1]
\end{document}
```

---

Adding some more smashed rules to illustrate exact separation achieved:

```
\documentclass{article}\setlength{\textwidth}{200pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{listparameters=\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1]\strut\smash{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\dp\strutbox}}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
  Some content
  here, with its
  own box
\end{Verbatim}
\prevdepth\dp\strutbox

\noindent\kern-1.5pt\smash{\rule{3pt}{\ht\strutbox}}\kern-1.5pt\kern\parindent\smash{\rule{1pt}{\ht\strutbox}}\lipsum[2][1]
\end{document}
```

We need a `\strut` in last line above frame.  We have set all extra space to zero.  This document has not modified `\parskip` because it defaults to `0pt plus 1pt`.  Achieving "exact smae space before and after" would require to say "space between what and what".  It is clear where we start measuring space either at top or bottom frame, it is not clear where we stop measuring space? is it distance to nearest ink, so depends whether lines contains descenders (for top) or ascenders (for bottom), or are we measuring distance to baselines.  If latter case we should probably not insist on same space above and below, because the situation with letters is not symmetric: they rise higher than they descend.

[image: rules]

Comment: the testing small vertical rule really abuts precisely to bottom of frame, although for example on my PDF viewer anti-aliasing or other effect at some point made me think there was overlap, but there is none,  adding a horizontal displacement (not indicated here) allowed me to verity it (I could have gone the `\showoutput` way)

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain in your answer what `\prevdepth\dp\strutbox` does? Also, there is still some space on top of the `N` (of the following paragraph) while there is no space under the `g` (of the preceding paragraph). Finally, do you know what is causing the additional vertical spacing in my original question?

Comment: Oh, Googling your command [I found out](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/misc/tex/common/teTeX-1.0.1/lib/texmf/tex/context/base/supp-box.tex) that `\nointerlineskip` suppresses `parskip`. I think this command should be used instead.

Comment: `\nointerlineskip` expands to `\prevdepth -\@m \p@` i.e. to setting the `\prevdepth` to `-1000pt`.  This is completely unrelated to the `\parskip` value.  Indeed my advice has no relation to effect of the  `\parskip` in the document as you can see by setting it to some large value for example `50pt` in the document (I am not talking here about the parameters you modify via `\fvset`).  Then you will see the effect of the parskip glue insertion after the framed box.  And it turns out fancyvrb code induces it also above the framed box.  For `\prevdepth` see TeX by Topic.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting TeX by Topic! It explains that `\prevdepth` is TeX's perceived depth of the previous box. It seems like you assign to it (although there is no `=` in your code) to a *strut*'s depth with `\dp\strut`, which leaves a gap on top of the following paragraph. Setting `\prevdepth` to `-1000pt` prevents any glue from being inserted, treating the next box as the first one in a vertical list. So, the correct solution is using a `\AddToHook` with `\nointerlineskip` and setting a desired `\topsep` for equal top/bottom spacing. Is it correct?

Comment: First of all, fancyvrb uses a trivlist; this will insert topsep and partopsep *above* and *below*. Via `\fvset` you set them to zero (their default appear to be `8pt` and `2pt` respectively plus stretch and shrink.  Then there will be `\parskip` glue before and after.  But default is `0pt` (plus stretch of `1pt`).  Now I looked at the box output and turns out fancyvrb framing puts the lower rule inside a `\hbox`. And this box has zero depth, and the reference point of the box is at lower side of bottom rule.  Now if you do your `\fvset` to set to zero the trivlist extra spaces, and then

Comment: tart next paragraph with `\smash{\rule{1pt}{\baselineskip}}A` you will see that TeX locates the baseline of next paragraph exactly baselineskip away from bottom of bottom rule.  By faking the `\prevdepth` to be the depth of the strutbox, we are cheating and telling TeX to consider the last "baseline" was higher up, so it will position the baseline of new paragraph higher up.

Comment: So in conclusion I do not quite understand why you are so keen on using `\nointerlineskip`.  Returning to my explanations, in this example the baselineskip is 12pt, and the strutbox has a depth of 3.6pt. So the baseline of paragraph after frame will be located (once you have zeroed the topsep and partopsep) exactly 8.4pt underneath the bottom part of the frame.  That is, actually, the height of a `\strut`.

Comment: I would recommend ending the material above the frame with a  strut. To ensure some depth, else it depends if this material has descenders.  And it does not look really good to me to zero completely the topsep and partopsep.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation. I looked at `texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty` and I cannot see the `trivlist` you're referring to. How would you zero `trivlist` extra spaces? Finally, my objective is/was to have the same spacing before and after the `Verbatim` environment and I thought of using `Verbatim`'s `vspace` option. When I set it to zero, I notice that it was not equally zero on both sides. That's why I wrote this question. To control the exact spacing.

Comment: Apologies! You are absolutely right, no `trivlist` is used by fancyvrb but its `\FV@ListVSpace` imitates things typically done by `trivlist`, and certainly was modeled on it, inclusive of how vertical spaces is handled before and after... and meaning of `\partopsep` and `\topsep`.  This is also the macro where the `vspace` option has an effect (via `\FancyVerbVspace`).

Comment: Vertical space is always added by TeX when it handles paragraphs. I feel you expected `vspace` option if set to zero, to completely cancel space before and after framing: by this perhaps you want highest ascender to touch the bottom of the frame?, but TeX will always inject the `\parskip` and try to achieve a `\baselineskip` between successive lines. Here the effect of fancyvrb way of doing framing has as result that TeX considers baseline was right at bottom frame if you set to zero all extra spacing added by fancyvrb.

Comment: Let me ask you my last question. How would you set both top and bottom space to the exact same value (which is my ultimate goal besides learning TeX)? Thank you so much for your wisdom and patience.

Comment: To answer your query, I need to know what you consider space: if the last line above frame contains a `p`, do you want it to touch the top frame? but if that line contains no descenders, only  say `baba`, then should the frame touch the bottom of `baba`? and symmetrically below the frame with respect to ascenders? Note that how TeX will locate the frame on the page will depend on the material before it.

Comment: with your `fvset` to set to zero topsep and partopsep, and in a document leaving `\parskip` to zero too, then if last line above frame contains a `\strut`, the distance of top of frame to last baseline should be the `\dp\strutbox`, and with the `\prevdepth=\dp\strutbox`, after the frame, the distance of bottom of frame to newt basline will be the `\ht\strutbox`.  This is not symmetrical but logical because letters have higher ascenders than descenders.

Comment: I'll answer ‘what I consider space’ with what I'd like to achieve since it would be more effective. The code inserts should look as if they are part of the paragraph, even though they are framed. Therefore, some uniform baseline spacing would be expected. By default, they have extra white space, which makes them look like paragraphs on their own. When I tried to shrink the space, I noticed spacing was not even. Hence, I posted my question to understand what was happening.

Comment: Then some polishing of my answer should be added to compensate the "thickness" of framing... I did not check what is actual value used by Verbatim...

Comment: Thanks for engaging! <3